# ListBox get value/display members

Tags: vb.net

How to loop through selected items and get value member and display member of each. [multiline listbox]

```
LB_Sentences.DataSource = Nothing
LB_Sentences.DataSource = GetTable(False)
LB_Sentences.ValueMember = "Id"
LB_Sentences.DisplayMember = "Name"
LB_Sentences.SelectedIndex = -1

For i As Integer = 0 To LB_Sentences.SelectedItems.Count - 1
   Dim id as integer = LB_Sentences.??
   Dim name as integer = LB_Sentences.??
Next
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably you want to reduce the number of questions to 1 or 2, as it probably is the reason for the downvotes. Also, is this `winform`?

Comment: Those are my questions, is there questions limit or? I think its easy to answer by middle experienced user and would be helpfull for other people.

Comment: No, there isn't any limit of course. But typically (that means: majority), people will have small number of questions. The reason I mention this is to help you get answer of course, since I note the reason for Close Vote in your question is "Too Board" (once you have enough reputation you can see the close vote)

Comment: Yes, there is a limit.  That limit is 1.  If you have four questions to ask then you make four posts.

Comment: @lan ok guys let me limit to two questions then... Please upvote after change.

Comment: Or, limit it to one like you're supposed to and ask any subsequent questions in new posts.

Comment: @jmcilhinney done, waiting for answers

Comment: Ok, great. Upvoted. By this, at least you do not have negative question's vote. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, while a `For` loop is not wrong here, a `For Each` loop is more appropriate.

As for the question, you can get the display member value by calling the `GetItemText` method.  Just note that that will get the `String` displayed in the `ListBox` so, if the actual member is not type `String`, you're not actually getting that member's value.

With regards to the value member, there's nothing to do that for you so you have to do it yourself.  Assuming that your data source is a `DataTable` in this case, you just have to get each item as a `DataRowView` and then get the value from the column as you always would.  You can do the same for the display member if you need other than a `String`.

```
For Each rowView As DataRowView In myListBox.SelectedItems
    name = myListBox.GetItemText(rowView)
    id = CInt(rowView("Id"))

    '...
Next
```

Comment: do i have to say Id (rowView(Ïd")? or something like get value? Would like to avoid putting table column names on form directly.

Comment: You could use `id = CInt(rowView(myListBox.ValueMember))` but you still have to know what type that column is in order to cast it as the appropriate type.  If you're dealing with IDs though, I'm guessing that it's the same type, either `Integer` or `Long`, every time.

Comment: and one more thing is there possibility within your loop to unselect every row within loop? If so how?

Comment: You can't change the list being enumerated in a `For Each` loop.  I'd probably set the `SelectedItem` to `Nothing` to the `SelectedIndex` to -1 at the end of the loop to clear the selection.  If you really wanted to do it inside the loop then I'd probably copy the contents of the `SelectedIndices` to an array and then loop through that, using the indexes to get the items and also to pass to `SetItemSelected` to unselect each item in turn.

Comment: Why are you making that diabolical suggestion when I already told you how to unselect items in the loop with my previous comment?